# Pg not working heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've litterally tried every possible solution on the Internet and still no luck with implmeeting the database

EDIT: for further code review here's the github.com link
https://github.com/flaminggenius/lit-fortress/blob/lit-fortress/src/server/server.js

I got this from the heroku docs but it doesn't do anything

```
    var con = "postgres://username:pass@host:port/database"; //yes I did actually get the credentials from heroku but I'm not putting them here
    pg.defaults.ssl = true;
    pg.connect(con, function(err, client) {
     if (err) {
      console.log (err);
      console.log ("POSTGRES FAILED TO CONNECT");
     }
     console.log('Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...');

  client
 .query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;')
.on('row', function(row) {
  console.log (JSON.stringify(row));
 });
});
```

This doesn't crash the app  but if I change the `client` to

`client.query ("INSERT INTO users SET name='joey'");`

The app then crashes

Can anyone help me here are some questions I need answered

1.How do I properly establish a connection
2.How do I end connection (pg.end?)
3.How do I insert data?
4.How do I retrieve data

Before anyone says "what have you tried?" I have lithe rally done every Web search I could possibly think of for nodeJS,heroku, and pg and every link the code ether crashes the app or doesn't work....

Here is log

```
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:   syscall: 'connect', 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:   address: '10.179.216.254', 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:   port: 3306, 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:   fatal: true } 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1: Connected to postgres!      Getting schemas... 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1: events.js:160 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:       ^ 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1: error: syntax error at or near "SET" 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11) 
Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at  Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:381:17) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:22) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1:     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:548:20) 
Dec 01 11:18:59 masswarfare-dev app/web.1: [19:18:58] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... `
```

Package.json

```
{
 "name": "masswarfare",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "A simple Agar.io clone",
 "main": "server/server.js",
"scripts": {
 "build": "gulp build",
 "start": "gulp run",
 "watch": "gulp watch",
 "test": "gulp test"
},
"repository": {
 "type": "git",
 "url":   "https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone.git"
 },
 "author": "Huy Tran",
 "license": "MIT",
 "contributors": [
  "Igor Antun <igorantunc@hotmail.com> (https://github.com/IgorAntun)",
  "Bjarne Oeverli <bjarne.oeverli@gmail.com> (https://github.com/bjarneo)",
   "Chris Morgan <chris.j.r.morgan@gmail.com> (https://github.com/drpotato)",
    "PET Computação UFPR <pet@inf.ufpr.br> (http://pet.inf.ufpr.br)",
   "Saren Currie <saren@sarencurrie.com> (https://github.com/SarenCurrie)",
   "Nguyen Huu Thanh <giongto35@yahoo.com> (https://github.com/giongto35)",
   "Ariamiro <dossantosgusmaosavio@gmail.com> (https://github.com/Ariamiro)",
  "VILLERS Mickaël <mickael.villers@epitech.eu> (https://github.com/villers)",
   "Dan Prince <dan@astrealdynamics.co.uk> (https://github.com/danprince)",
    "Kostas Bariotis <konmpar@gmail.com> (https://github.com/kbariotis)",
   "Jerry Xu <jerryxu23@gmail.com> (https://github.com/abalabahaha)",
    "Damian Dlugosz <bigfootdd@gmail.com> (https://github.com/bigfoot90)",
    "Juha Tauriainen <juha@bin.fi> (https://github.com/JuhQ)",
   "Madara Uchiha <me@madara.ninja> (https://github.com/MadaraUchiha)",
   "Keith Groves <Keithalgroves@gmail.com> (https://github.com/buskcoin)",
   "wb9688 <wbertrums@gmail.com> (https://github.com/wb9688)"
  ],
 "dependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "express": "^4.13.4",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
  "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.1",
  "gulp-mocha": "^2.2.0",
  "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.7",
  "gulp-todo": "^4.1.0",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
  "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
  "jshint": "^2.9.2",
   "mocha": "^2.5.3",
  "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
  "sat": "^0.5.0",
  "simple-quadtree": "^0.1.3",
  "socket.io": "^1.4.6",
  "socket.io-client": "^1.4.6",
  "sync-request": "^3.0.1",
  "webpack": "^1.13.1",
  "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
  "mysql": "^2.5.5",
  "pg": "^6.1.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Does it work on your dev box?

Comment: What do you mean by dev box

Comment: Also, run 'heroku logs' from your terminal and let us know why error is reported.

Comment: I mean your local development machine.

Comment: It'd also help if you can post your package.json and the rest of the file the above snippets came from

Comment: I'm not running it locally I have a separate project created to run development builds so it runs on a "live" server I attached the logs

Comment: @Paul I can attach the package.json but the server.js spans almost 1000 lines....

Comment: @Paul attached package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your logs:

`Dec 01 11:18:58 masswarfare-dev app/web.1: error: syntax error at or near "SET"`

Doing a quick scan of the Postgres docs tells me that your query of

`INSERT INTO users SET name='joey'`

Is, in fact, invalid syntax.  SET is a command that is used with UPDATE queries, not INSERT queries.  A correct INSERT query would look like:

```
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('joey');
```

As a side note, you really should try and run your code locally, even if it's just your test suite as it's often easier to find this kind of thing early.

Further, if your `server.js` is 1000 lines, I would argue that you're doing it wrong.  The code will  be *much* more maintainable if you break things out into smaller files that you can compose.  I rarely have to scroll a file, and never more than two pages.

Comment: While this turns out to be true (I'm used to using sql with php) it also turns out I'm getting ECONNREFUSED in pg/lib/connection.js

Comment: Your error indicated that you successfully connected, but then passed bad SQL.  When are you seeing the ECONNREFUSED?  I would look into whether or not the postgres instance is running, and whether there's any firewalls blocking on the port it's listening on in that case.

Comment: It's all good now it was the con string I was passing was missing a few letrees in the pass but all good and working now